# Supporting my step daughter to come with me to the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, cambodian-citizens

I am a 75 year old Brit who has worked in developing countries for 47 years, the last 17 in Cambodia where I still am. I have been married to a Cambodian lady for 14 years and have taken care of her daughter who is now 24 and very well educated, 2 degrees in accountancy and office management. I plan to retire to UK with my wife (60)and have no problem satisfying the financial aspects. We would like to have our daughter with us to assist us in our old age and I would plan pay to put our daughter in college and she would live with us. Would this be possible?

Comment: Did you adopt your daughter?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan as far as I can tell, parents cannot sponsor their children unless they are under 18, so it wouldn't matter whether the stepfather had adopted his stepdaughter.

Comment: @phoog what about [derivative rights of residence](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/derivative-rights-of-residence)?

Comment: @StrongBad That might work under Ruiz Zambrano, in which case it would not allow the daughter to bring her own family, or to aquire a permanent right of residence.  It is also an EU/EEA scheme, so it may cease to be available in the next few years.

Comment: Can you meet the financial requirements of either [Tier 1 Investor](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-investor/eligibility) (£2,000,000) or [Tier 1 Entrepreneur](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur/access-to-200000-investment-funds) (£200,000)?

Comment: @phoog is right